# Using os-preprocessor in python

Tags: python

How do i use os-preprocessor macros in `python` for implementing os-specific code.

for example in C/C++ we use below.

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    //linux code goes here
#elif _WIN32
    //windows code goes here
#else
   //Other OS code goes here
#endif
```

is something similar exists for python too.

Comment: There is no preprocessor in python but you can use sys module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import sys module

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32': 
    #windows code
elif sys.platform == 'linux':
    #linux code
```